# Are questions about other Emacs-like editors on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm currently investigating in edwin, an Emacs-like editor bundled with MIT Scheme.  The very moment I've tried to start it up, I've found an interesting question for the Stackexchange, but am not sure whether editors other than GNU Emacs are on-topic.  Is there a policy on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are questions about getting emacs-like behavior in other things on topic?](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27/are-questions-about-getting-emacs-like-behavior-in-other-things-on-topic)

Comment: Hm, I'm less sure on this considering that edwin is implemented in Scheme *and* can be customized in Scheme, too.  This makes it different from programs that can be merely tought Emacs keybindings.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, edwin is different from jmacs/µemacs/…, but still, it's an editor that doesn't run Emacs Lisp packages. That's what makes it off-topic in my book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because look at Gilles comment.

Comment: @King This is *meta* and the question is about the scope of emacs.stackexchange, isn't it the textbook example of an *on-topic* question? `;)` Duplicate is something else entirely, of course.

Comment: @T.Verron, you are right. Sorry, that was a mistake on my part.